# SalesForce SOQL issue with query

Tags: python, sql, salesforce, soql, salesforce-communities

I've been trying to pull a table from sales force into a jupyter notebook to make as a dataframe. When I create the query and try executing it, I get this message:

Malformed request https://lumn.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v42.0/query/?q=SELECT+WhoId%2C+ActivityDate%2C+OwnerId%2C+IsDeleted%2C+AccountId%2C+IsClosed%2C+CreatedDate%.... Response content: [{'message': "exceeded 100000 distinct who/what's", 'errorCode': 'OPERATION_TOO_LARGE'}]

I pulled in another table successfully using **sf.query_all()**, which had more data than 100000 rows so I'm stumped on this one and there is not a lot of documentation on what to do at this point since it doesn't give me a **recordsURL** to pull in increments. I also tried to see if **sf.bulk.Task.query_all()** would work, but it does not do it either. As well I tried to pull in this data through excel and was given the same error message. The project I'm working on does not filter this table down in any way so it consequently has to pull all from these columns I am working with. If anyone has any idea how to circumvent this please share!

Answer (score 1):

Not familiar with this error but you might give "PK chunking" a go, https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/async_api_headers_enable_pk_chunking.htm

And there's some good reading on work with huge tables in general, https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp.meta/salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp/ldv_deployments_introduction.htm